# Make canvas image point towards mouse while following

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, trigonometry

I have a rocket that is following the mouse with a slight delay in my canvas, and I want it to point towards the mouse while it's traveling around. I have almost gotten it, as you can see in my fiddle **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/v6zbu/1/)**. My problem is that the rotation is kind of opposite of the direction I want it to be, and it's just weird and jiggely.

The JS i'm using to get it to do so in my canvas is:

```
ctx.save();
                var offsetY = targetToGo.x - shape.y ;
                var offsetX = targetToGo.y - shape.x ;
                var degrees = -Math.atan2(offsetY,offsetX);                     
                    ctx.translate(shape.x, shape.y);

                    ctx.rotate(degrees);

                    ctx.drawImage(shape.image,-shape.image.width/2,-shape.image.width/2);

                    ctx.restore();
```

Is it the canvas code or the math that is wrong? I'm bad at both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change line

```
var degrees = -Math.atan2(offsetY,offsetX);
```

to

```
var degrees = Math.atan2(offsetY,-offsetX);
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/v6zbu/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

The math is wrong. Negating offsetY and offsetX will fix it.

```
var degrees = -Math.atan2(-offsetY, -offsetX);
```

Also the angle is not in degrees but radians.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the offset like this.

```
var offsetY = targetToGo.x - shape.x ;    
var offsetX = targetToGo.y - shape.y ;
```

And apply this rotation.

```
ctx.rotate(degrees+Math.PI);
```